# How can I optimize my code and refactor it when value changes put effect on other

Tags: swift

I have a struct witch got 10 variables, changes on this variables cause `successful` variable became **false**, I have to repeat my code for all 10 variable to cover all, successful variable has own method to determine if it is true, this function would be called just in some cases but I am not going call that function each time, as I said just in some case would be called, and that method would update successful variable as well. The issue is here that I am repeating codes for 10 times, is there a way to stop repeating with better approach?

```
struct SomeType {
    
    var value1: Bool { didSet(oldValue) { if (oldValue != value1) { successful = false } } }
    var value2: Bool { didSet(oldValue) { if (oldValue != value2) { successful = false } } }
    var value3: Bool { didSet(oldValue) { if (oldValue != value3) { successful = false } } }
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    var value10: Bool { didSet(oldValue) { if (oldValue != value10) { successful = false } } }
    
    var successful: Bool
    
    // some other codes ...
    
    mutating func successfulFunc() {
        successful = true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why not use an array of booleans?

Comment: @George: It is good idea, but i cannot, because in real project the variables has special names like: name, address, ... . I just simplified my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

As George notes, one way to attack this is with an array of Bools, particularly since you can easily check for equality.

```
struct SomeType {
    private var value = Array(repeating: false, count: 10)
    private var successValue: [Bool]

    init() { successValue = value }

    var value0: Bool { value[0] }
    var value1: Bool { value[1] }
    var value2: Bool { value[2] }
    // ...
    var value9: Bool { value[9] }

    var successful: Bool { successValue == value }

    mutating func successfulFunc() {
        successValue = value
    }

}
```

You can push this even further to reduce code duplication and allow different types for each property using `@dynamicMemberLookup` and a nested type:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct SomeType {
    struct SomeTypeValue: Equatable {
        var value1 = false
        var value2 = false
        var value3 = false
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
        var value10 = false
    }

    private var value = SomeTypeValue()
    private var successValue = SomeTypeValue()

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<SomeTypeValue, T>) -> T {
        get { value[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { value[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }

    var successful: Bool { value == successValue }

    mutating func successfulFunc() {
        successValue = value
    }
}
```

This pushes all the data into a sub-value, and then tracks whether it has changed since `successfulFunc` was called. And you can then make that more generic:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct SuccessChecker<Value: Equatable> {

    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
        self.successValue = value
    }
    private var value: Value
    private var successValue: Value

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Value, T>) -> T {
        get { value[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { value[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }

    var successful: Bool { value == successValue }

    mutating func successfulFunc() {
        successValue = value
    }
}

let someType = SuccessChecker(value: SomeType())
```

This could also be turned into a property wrapper, but the syntax gets a little awkward, because you need to add an underscore to access `successful`:

```
@propertyWrapper
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct SuccessChecker<Value: Equatable> {

    init(wrappedValue value: Value) {
        self.wrappedValue = value
        self.successValue = value
    }
    var wrappedValue: Value
    private var successValue: Value

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Value, T>) -> T {
        get { wrappedValue[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { wrappedValue[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }

    var successful: Bool { wrappedValue == successValue }

    mutating func successfulFunc() {
        successValue = wrappedValue
    }
}

@SuccessChecker var someType = SomeType()
print(_someType.successful)
```

Even so, that could be useful.